# Capture and display laravel validation errors returned from an $http.post in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, validation, laravel-5

i am a newbie to laravel and laravel 5 and so ar i am having such a hard time, it's just problem after problem, my current issues is this, i am using angular js on my frontend, so i already have client side validation working and implemented, now when i send my form via $http.post the form is also validated on the server, if there are validation errors it returns the whole page in the response but what i want is only the errors returned as json, i am currently trying my hands on user registration not a custom one but the one that already comes with **laravel 5**.

this is my register.js:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('vendor').controller('RegisterController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

        $scope.d = {};

        $scope.register = function() {

            $http.post(
                '/auth/register',
                {
                    _token: $scope.d._token,
                    email: $scope.d.email,
                    password: $scope.d.password,
                    password_confirmation: $scope.d.password_confirmation
                },
                {
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            ).success(function(data) {
                // get errors here
            });
        };

    }]);

}) ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to capture and log the errors like so:

```
        $http.post(
            '/auth/register',
            {
                _token: $scope.d._token,
                email: $scope.d.email,
                password: $scope.d.password,
                password_confirmation: $scope.d.password_confirmation
            },
            {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            }
        ).success(function(data) {
            // successs
        }).error(function(error) {
            // error
            console.log(error);
        });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http